# Highchart not showing from JSON data

Tags: php, arrays, json, charts, highcharts

I'm trying to display a line chart with json data, but with there, $_GET from the json I have the chart doesn't appear, here's my code :

```
$(function () {
            var chart;
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $.getJSON("master/proyek/s-curve.php", function(json) {
                
                    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                        chart: {
                            renderTo: 'scurve',
                            type: 'line'
                        },
                        credits: {
                             enabled: false
                        }, 
                        title: {
                            text: 'S-Curve Balai'
                            
                        },
                        subtitle: {
                            text: ''
                        
                        },
                        xAxis: {
                            categories: ['M1', 'M2', 'M3', 'M4']
                        },
                        yAxis: {
                            title: {
                                text: ''
                            },
                            plotLines: [{
                                value: 1,
                                width: 1,
                                color: '#808080'
                            }]
                        },
                        tooltip: {
                            formatter: function() {
                                    return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                                    this.x +': '+ this.y;
                            }
                        },
                        legend: {
                             layout: 'horizontal',
                        },
                        plotOptions: {
                            line: {
                                dataLabels: {
                                    enabled: true,
                                       distance: 100,
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        series: json,
                    });
                });
            
            });
            
        });
```

and this my s-curve.php :

```
<?php
header("Content-type: application/json");
require_once "config/database.php";
$db = new database();
$mysqli = $db->connect();
$balai = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_GET['balai']);
if ($balai == 'bl-1') {
    $sql = "SELECT plan, actual FROM scurve1 ORDER BY id ASC";
} else if ($balai == 'bl-2') {
    $sql = "SELECT plan, actual FROM scurve2 ORDER BY id ASC";
} else if ($balai == 'bl-3') {
    $sql = "SELECT plan, actual FROM scurve3 ORDER BY id ASC";
}
$hasil = array();
$hasil['name'] = 'Plan';
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
while ($data = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $hasil['data'][] = $data['plan'];
}

$hasil1 = array();
$hasil1['name'] = 'Actual';
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
while ($data = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $hasil1['data'][] = $data['actual'];
}

$nilai = array();
array_push($nilai, $hasil);
array_push($nilai, $hasil1);
print json_encode($nilai, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
$mysqli->close();
```

display my json from localhost/master/proyek/s-curve.php?balai=bl-1 :

[Display Json Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCtxt.jpg)

from my case above, can someone tell what error I can fix to be able to display the chart.

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). Even [if you are escaping inputs, it's not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187) You should always use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API instead of concatenating user-provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!

Comment: Btw try this once : https://3v4l.org/lhqMFm

Comment: hello @AnantKumarSingh  thank you very much for your help,  i have done what you applied but its still not working my chart still not showing. Or is there something I need to fix from my JS chart?

Comment: Hi @Identic 7, Your chart config and your data look correct. I have created this live example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9q8znr4h/ Please check the real value of json by adding `console.log(json)` one line above the `chart` variable assignment.

Comment: modify code like this and try : `while ($data = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $hasil[]=['name'=>'Plan', 'data' => $data['plan']];
    $hasil[]=['name'=>'Actual', 'data' => $data['actual']];
}`

Comment: thanks @ppotaczek , the code runs fine without the $_GET function there, now my problem is with the $_GET function, even though in my JSON file it works but the chart still doesn't show.

Comment: @Identic 7, Maybe the path to the json file is incorrect? There must be some error in a browser console, please check it.